# Grouping by using different sum from a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table:

timesheet (task_date, duration, billable)

The data is like this:

| task_date | duration | billable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | 5.0 | Y |
| 2020-01-02 | 3.0 | N |

I want to create sum on both billable and non-billable group by task_date. I have implemented like this:

```
select task_date,
(SELECT SUM(duration) FROM timesheet t2 where t2.task_date = t.task_date and t2.billable = 'Y') as billable,
(SELECT SUM(duration) FROM timesheet t2 where t2.task_date = t.task_date and t2.billable = 'N') as nonBillable,
FROM timesheet t
group by task_date
```

This seems to work.

| task_date | billable | nonBillable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | 5.0 | 3.0 |

I am wondering if it can be done any easier

Comment: `SUM(billable)` isn't going to be working, `billable` is a `varchar` and you can't `SUM` a `varchar`.

Comment: Thanks, it was a mistake, should be sum(duration), Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, don't use subqueries to the table again, that'll result in 3 "trips" to the table (`timesheet` in this case).

What you want is just conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT task_date,
       SUM(CASE billable WHEN 'Y' THEN duration END) AS billable, 
       SUM(CASE billable WHEN 'N' THEN duration END) AS non_billable
FROM dbo.timesheet
GROUP BY task_date;
```